# I want to obtain response of sub request in nginx module development

Tags: c, nginx, module

I am developing C modules in nginx

I want to issue a sub request and get a response(header,body)

The code I am writing now is as as follows

How can I get a response (heade, body) after executing the ngx_http_subrequest method?

```
    ps = ngx_palloc(r->pool, sizeof(ngx_http_post_subrequest_t));
if (ps == NULL) {
    return NGX_ERROR;
}
ps->handler = ngx_http_auth_request_done;
ps->data = "foo";


if (ngx_http_subrequest(r, &uri, NULL, &sr, ps, NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_IN_MEMORY) != NGX_OK)
{
    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_DEBUG, r->connection->log, 0, "subrequest is failed!!");
    return NGX_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ngx_http_auth_request_done is the handler you have defined which is the callback that handles the response of the subrequest. You are supposed to implement this function. If you look at it's signature, it has the request structure you have sent out. The request structure's upstream variable contains a buffer where the response is stored. r->upstream->buffer. You can look at nginx's own modules for how to parse the response.